# setuptools adding additional uninstallation steps

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation, setuptools, setup.py

I am creating a python package with setuptools and in the setup.py file, I add a couple extra steps to move files in the file system. I can easily install my package with pip and it works great. The problem is that when I do a pip uninstall, some unused files are left in the file system.

Is it possible to add extra steps in the setup.py file so that when someone issue a pip uninstall, it executes these extra steps to remove the unused files?